# Indent subsequent lines in `pre` code blocks

Tags: javascript, css

In most modern text editors long lines of text are beatifully wrapped at the same indent level as it's beginning.

Screenshot from Brackets:

[image]

The same, with interface elements, for better understanding:

[image]

But in CSS, with `pre { white-space: pre-wrap; }`, long lines are indented to the left side of the window:

```
<style>
pre {white-space: pre-wrap}
</style>

<pre>
function() {
    if (a == b) {
        alert("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
    }
}
</pre>
```

Result:

[image]

Obviously, it isn't very convenient to read.

And that's why most people use `pre { overflow-x: auto; }` instead of `pre { white-space: pre-wrap; }` for code blocks in sites they build.

Is it possible to simulate something similar to Brackets with CSS/JS?

Also, this issue is probably solved in some library, like Google Prettify, but I don't know.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why Palpatim removed "jquery" tag, because jQuery is usually used to make hard things easier (and my task is definitely hard), but due to my respect to his score, hm, okay.

Comment: The jquery tag was removed because 1) there's no indication you're using the library 2) you don't need to use that library for this problem - this can be solved using CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css like:

```
p {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Or refer to this - https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/